# convert NSNumber to float type of an entity attribute in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, type-conversion

How can I convert a NSNumber to float for a attribute in CoreData ?
Lets say, myNSNumber is a variable of type NSNumber, and myAttribute is type of float of class
myEntityclass :

```
myEntityclass.myAttribute = myNSNumber
```

I am under MacOS 10.15  , Xcode 12.2 , Swift V?

Many discussions I have seen already, but none of them worked for me. I either get truncated value (e.g. -60. instead of -60.71 ). or nil or a dump.

```
myEntityclass.myAttribute =  Float(exactly:myNSNumber!).  // not ok
myEntityclass.myAttribute =  myNSNumber.floatValue.       // not ok
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you create your NSNumber, from a float?

Comment: Calling `floatValue` is the correct way. If if's *not ok* there is another issue.

Comment: Thank you Koen and Vadian : Indeed myNSNumber is more a string than a number. That's where the problem comes from.

Comment: “More a string than a number” doesn’t make sense if it’s an `NSNumber`. Do you have a number or a sting?

Comment: Yes, right.. more precise:  a forced conversion from a string to NSNumber failed. There was indeed no issue with floatValue.